# Can Lightroom catalogs be created in any other program?

Tags: metadata, lightroom-catalog, ipad, photo-viewer

I would like to use a software such as [Mosaic](http://www.mosaicarchive.com/lightroom-ipad-web-app-mosaic-view/) to view my photos on my iPad. However, I would prefer not to buy Lightroom, as I (currently) have no use for the RAW editing. So, can Lightroom catalogs be created with any other program? Or are there alternative setups to create a catalog of photos with metadata to be synced with iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightroom's catalogs are SQlite databases, so it should be possible to create them in other programs.

Comment: Bearing in mind that Adobe would probably unleash its legal department on anyone who did this in a publicly available program. The database itself is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom uses, or can use and generate, [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) [Sidecar files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidecar_file) there are a number of free &/or open source applications that can do the same:

- ExifTool by Phil Harvey, open source Perl module or command line. Can read/write XMP, supports custom XMP schema (platform independent)
- Exiv2 - Open Source C++ library and command line utility to manage image metadata, including some XMP properties.
- darktable - RAW developer, can read/write XMP in supported file formats (Linux, Mac OS X)
- digiKam - open source (GPL) image tagger and organiser (Linux, Mac OS X, MS Windows)
- F-Spot - Linux/GNOME photo manager and editor
- Geeqie - Lightweight Gtk+ based image manager (formerly GQView)
- GIMP - GNU Image Manipulation Program
- Gwenview - Linux/KDE photo manager and editor
- Photini - Python and exiv2 based metadata editor
- Shotwell - Linux/GNOME photo manager, can read/write Exif, IPTC and XMP metadata
- CC PDF Converter - A free open source (GPL) program to convert documents to PDF with embedded Creative-Commons license (MS Windows).
- Alfresco - open source CMS, DAM component can read/write XMP (MS Windows, Linux)
- Notre-DAM - Open source DAM solution, relies heavily on XMP capabilities
- ResourceSpace - Open source DAM concentrating on metadata; can be extended with exiftool to read/write many XMP properties
- Razuna - Open source DAM solution, can read/write XMP in supported file formats (platform independent, Java)
- Zenphoto - open source multimedia CMS, maps XMP attributes to image fields and allows XMP based filtering (PHP based).

The base XMP toolkit is available in various languages including [python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xmp-toolkit/2.0.1) so rolling your own should be quite practical.

I did find a really good page on the support for and pitfalls of using XMP on iPad [here](http://metadatadeluxe.pbworks.com/w/page/49203730/Apple%20iPad) if it is of any use to you!

Comment: Being able to create XMP files isn't the same thing as building a Lightroom catalog.